# How to add specific string after a set of value

Tags: shell, scripting

For example, i have the file with following entries:-

```
10.59.37.9      strvasr5267
10.59.37.11     strvasr5268
10.59.37.15     strvasr5279
10.59.37.16     strvasr5303
```

and i want to add  `# "TRENDS:*,netstat:netstat|netstat1|netstat2|netstat3"` after each hostname like:-

```
10.59.37.9  strvasr5267   # "TRENDS:*,netstat:netstat|netstat1|netstat2|netstat3"
```

Is there any loop in which i can read both ip's and hostname and then add above string after hostname...

Comment: why do you need to go to the trouble of reading the IP and name for each line when it looks like you want to add a constant string on every line?

Comment: yes.correct .i want to add a contant string after everyline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to add the string:

```
sed -i 's/$/   # "TRENDS:*,netstat:netstat|netstat1|netstat2|netstat3"/' file
```

If you need to use the ip and hostname in a shell loop:

```
while read -r ip name; do
    do_something_with "$ip" "$name"
    printf '%s\t%s\t# "TRENDS:*,netstat:netstat|netstat1|netstat2|netstat3"\n' "$ip" "$name"
done
```

Comment: This `sed` will add the string if the line is empty.

Comment: @iamauser how about `sed '/[^[:blank:]]/ s/$/ the string/' file` to modify the line only when there is a non-blank character

Answer (score 0):

You can add a constant string at the end of each line with simple `sed` command,

```
 sed -i 's/[0-9].*$/& # "TRENDS:*,netstat:netstat|netstat1|netstat2|netstat3"/g' file
```

As OP pointed out, why you need to read IP that are inside file. Update your question to get an updated answer.